# How to Retrieve Http header responses of Embed Iframe in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest, httpresponse

i have the laravel site for collecting data from many sources..
one of our plan is get data from some other sites and now we did manually.
now i want to make embed page in my laravel site (blade) and i want to get the **http response** of embed page include the iframe..

`<iframe>`

That site is returned some data in Response body of page as json Data ..
and i want to got them in my site .. for now just i have the problem for getting the response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGpJG.png)

Comment: please be more precise with your question : what do you mean by "http response"? http status code? html body? and where do you wants to get it? into a variable? to display it?

Comment: @PierreAvinain i'm explain in question.